# Outputting a vector with repeated values

Tags: r, vector

To keep my script records clean, I'd like to output vector inputs with rep() instead of repeated values in chain. Please see my example below, using dput():

```
v<-c(rep(1,2), rep(2,4), rep(NA,5))
dput(v)
>c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
unknown_function(v)
>c(rep(1,2), rep(2,4), rep(NA,5))
```

Surely trivial, but I cannot find any simple solution. Suggestions for unknown_function(), please?

Comment: Basically, `rle(v)` would do most of the job. The only problem are your `NA` values. `rle` treats them as a statistician would, which means, it doesn't assume they are the same values. A conversion to character is not always without loss of precision. If that is not an issue (e.g., you have only integer values), Gabor's answer does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function using the stucture of `rle` and change it to crunch also `NA` and combine it with the method from [@g-grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59719734/10488504).

```
dputRle <- function (x, nmin=3) {
  if (!is.vector(x) && !is.list(x)) 
    stop("'x' must be a vector of an atomic type")
  n <- length(x)
  if (n <= 1L) 
    return(x)
  y <- x[-1L] != x[-n] | is.na(x[-1L]) != is.na(x[-n])
  i <- c(which(y), n)
  lengths = diff(c(0L, i))
  paste0("c(", toString(unlist(sapply(seq(i), function(y) {
    if(lengths[y] <= nmin) {rep(x[i[y]], lengths[y])
    } else {paste0("rep(", x[i[y]], ",", lengths[y], ")")}
  }))), ")")
}

v <- c(rep(1,2), rep(2,4), rep(NA,5), 1)
dputRle(v, 1)
#[1] "c(rep(1,2), rep(2,4), rep(NA,5), 1)"
dputRle(v)
#"c(1, 1, rep(2,4), rep(NA,5), 1)"

v <- 1
dputRle(v)
#[1] 1

v <- numeric(0)
dputRle(v)
#numeric(0)
```

Or alternative.

```
dputRle2 <- function (x) {
  if (!is.vector(x) && !is.list(x)) 
    stop("'x' must be a vector of an atomic type")
  n <- length(x)
  if (n <= 1L) 
    return(x)
  y <- x[-1L] != x[-n] | is.na(x[-1L]) != is.na(x[-n])
  i <- c(which(y), n)
  paste0("rep(c(", toString(x[i]), "), c(", toString(diff(c(0L, i))), "))")
}

v <- c(rep(1,2), rep(2,4), rep(NA,5), 1)
dputRle2(v)
#[1] "rep(c(1, 2, NA, 1), c(2, 4, 5, 1))"
```

There are some ways to use `rle` with `c` and `rep`. All of the following will produce the same vector.

```
c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
c(1, rep(2, 2), rep(3, 3))
c(1, rep(c(2, 3), c(2, 3)))
rep(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 2, 3))
rep(1:3, 1:3)
```

Comment: This was genius. I was particularly intrigued by the second version.

Answer (score 5):

`rle` will compute the values and lengths and from that we can paste it together:

```
with(rle(format(v)), paste0("c(", toString(paste0("rep(", values, ",", lengths, ")")), ")"))
## [1] "c(rep( 1,2), rep( 2,4), rep(NA,5))"
```